# VM Ubuntu: Android Emulator won't start from Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, virtual-machine, adt

I have created a VM Ubuntu 14.04 using Vmware Player, and I've installed the ADT environment for Android Development.
I have created a new Android emulator using the shortcuts present in Eclipse; when I tried to start emulator I got the following known error:

> Starting emulator for AVD 'AVD_for_Nexus_5_by_Google'
>   ERROR: 32-bit Linux Android emulator binaries are DEPRECATED, to use them
>          you will have to do at least one of the following:
>          - Use the '-force-32bit' option when invoking 'emulator'.
>          - Set ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT to 'true' in your environment.
>          Either one will allow you to use the 32-bit binaries, but please be
>          aware that these will disappear in a future Android SDK release.
>          Consider moving to a 64-bit Linux system before that happens.

I fixed it in both ways: putting a variable in my .bashrc:

```
export ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT=true
```

and also setting the emulator option in the Eclipse preference dialog:

[image]

Nevertheless, every time I try to start the emulator I got always the same error.

The wierd thing is that if I try to start the emulator from a bash window, it starts normally. 
This could have been a boring workaround, but I would have been happy anyway. The problem is that when I try to deploy an application from Eclipse, the emulator started in this way is shown as "Offline" and I cannot run any application on it. Possibly I can upload the apk into the emulator from the command line, but debugging the app would become a bit harder.

Has anyone got the same problem or does know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I found out a partial solution for connecting eclipse to the running emulator started by command line: the emulator MUST be started with no snapshots. 
Indeed, if I start the emulator without snaspshots, it become "online" in DDMS, and I can finally use it. 
Although this could be a bit annoying, because starting the emulator from scratch every time it takes a long time, at least I have a way to use it.
On the other hand, I don't know exactly the reason of this behavior, if someone has an answer it will be appreciated.
Moreover, I still do not have idea why I'm not able to start the emulator from Eclipse.